# Need more simulators for BlackBerry SDK 6.0

Tags: blackberry-simulator

I have installed BlackBerry SDK 6.0.It provides only one simulator:9800 simulator. As BB SDK 5.0 provides different simulators like 8520,9630, in the same way. I want to use more simulators to be used with BB SDK 6.0.

How can I download other simulators and use it with BB SDK 6.0 for testing. Please give me the link if possible from where I can download simulators. I am new to BB so don't have any proper idea about it.

Answer (score 0):

You can get them from http://us.blackberry.com/developers/resources/simulators.jsp. You need to choose the model, not the OS though. You can find out which models support 6.0 at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BlackBerry_OS.